# How to change the name of site only for the developers?

Tags: 8, configuration

I am new on Drupal 8 , in order to change the site name and the slogan , I want to change the site name just for the developers used my website

is there any way to do that?

I have implemented a code but I want to do it for just developers , is there any hook any way to do that?

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('system.site');
$config->set('name', "XXXXXXX"); 
$config->save();
```

Comment: You could put `$config['system.site']['name'] = 'Foobar';` in your settings.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way to use a settings.local.php file that is outside of your git repo.  Each developer can use this to setup their local environment with local DB, etc.

I tend to have a settings.local.php.example file in the repo that dev can copy to their settings.local.php file.

This file can contain any Drupal overrides you want, e.g.: As Leymannx said:  `$config['system.site']['name'] = 'Foobar'`.

See the [docs on overrides](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/configuration-api/configuration-override-system) for some details.

Drupal also has an [example of settings.local.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21example.settings.local.php/8.2.x).

You can also use this to do things like turn off caching and security checks locally.

NOTE: I think the current settings.php files automatically include a test / load for the settings.local.php file.  If not, just search for how to make sure it gets loaded.